# How to convert string date to date javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is like this :

```
createDate = '2016-07-12 09:09:38';
createDate = new Date(createDate);
console.log(createDate);
```

The result :  `Date {Invalid Date}`

I want the result like this :  `Date {Tue Jul 12 2016 09:53:13 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)}`

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: it logs this: 'Tue Jul 12 2016 09:09:38 GMT+0300 (IDT)'

Comment: @Uzi, any solution?

Comment: @Uzi not all browsers though since it's not a valid iso string

Comment: convert to iso format at source

Comment: Perhaps if you read [some doco for the `Date()` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), and used that in conjunction with some string manipulation functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this ISO-8601 format:

```
createDate = '2016-07-12T09:09:38';   //watch for the T in between
createDate = new Date(createDate);
console.log(createDate);
```

here UTC time zone used to interpret arguments.

[Check This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: If `createDate` is dinamyc. And the format like this : `createDate = '2016-07-12 09:09:38';`. How to change `createDate = '2016-07-12 09:09:38';` to `createDate = '2016-07-12T09:09:38';`?

Comment: you can use `createDate.replace(" ", "T");` assuming you have dynamic date string in `createDate` variable.

Comment: It's working in Firefox. But in Chrome, It's not working

Comment: @mosestoh I've tested it myself in chrome and it's working fine. try debugging. print `createDate` after using `replace()`. make sure that your dynamic data has only one space between the date and time.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322089/why-convert-string-date-to-date-javascript-not-working-in-chrome