# Why convert string date to date javascript not working in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

My code is like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var createDate = '2016-07-12 09:09:38';
    createDate = createDate.replace(" ", "T");
    createDate = new Date(createDate);
    console.log(createDate);
</script>
```

In Firefox :  `Date {Tue Jul 12 2016 09:09:38 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)}`

In Chrome : `Tue Jul 12 2016 16:09:38 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)`

Why the results are different in chrome?

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109894/new-date-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: I'm still confused. I try : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109894/new-date-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox. It's not working

Comment: I try : `createDate = "2016-07-12T09:09:38Z";`, the result `Date {Tue Jul 12 2016 16:09:38 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)}`. It's wrong. Should : `Date {Tue Jul 12 2016 09:09:38 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)}`

Comment: I try : `createDate = "2016-07-12T09:09:38+07:00";` and it's working

Comment: "2016-07-12T09:09:38Z" *is correctly* "Tue Jul 12 2016 16:09:38 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)" - not sure what the issue is.  "Z" means GMT time zone, which is clearly +7 hours on SE Asia - so 9am here (excl. summer time) is 4pm there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly tell JavaScript that the date you are storing is currently in UTC (which is the same a GMT). You do this by appending `Z`, which stands for [Zulu Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). If you don't specify it, it falls back to the browser's implementation of the format, which is inconsistent.

```
var createDate = '2016-07-12 09:09:38Z';
createDate = createDate.replace(" ", "T");
createDate = new Date(createDate);
```

When you log the variable to the Console, you may notice differences between the Date/Time shown still. It's important to note that the Date/Time is correct. Again, it relates to the browser's implementation of the formatting. You can confirm that the internal values are correct with:

```
console.log(createDate.toString())
console.log(createDate.toUTCString())
```

The `toString()` will return the Date/Time in the local Time Zone, and the `toUTCString()` will return it in UTC/GMT, which should match the value you created the object with.